# How to receive emails and store them automatically in Alfresco

Tags: outlook, alfresco

We are working with Alfresco 4.2.c community version and the need is to configure Alfresco to store automatically received emails (from Outlook) in a specific workspace.

I really need your help.

Comment: What does automatically mean here and how does Outlook matter in this context ?

Comment: In other words , pull e-mails just like a standard SMTP
server does, and store the e-mail messages in the repository along with the attachments. The desired result is when i receive an email in my outlook account then i wish to see it in some alfresco workspace.

Comment: Anybody knows how to do? I need your recommandations ? Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Alfresco does not have a pull mechanism include to get & store mails. But there is a push-style solution called "[Inbound Mail](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/concepts/email-inboundsmtp-props.html)".

This gives you the opportunity to send (e.g. by forwarding or via Outlook rule) mails to alfresco & get them automatically stored in a folder: [How Emails are handled](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Inbound_SMTP_Email_Server_Configuration#How_Email_Messages_are_Handled)

Comment: Here is a video that shows how to configure inbound email if you want to try it out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p17GkHsLdmc

Comment: Thank you a lot  Mr Jeff Potts , your video is very clear and interesting.

Comment: Thank you a lot alfrescian.

Answer (score 1):

For the simple configuration (known users, no other special requirements):

Basic configuration changes (tweak unknown/allowable/etc for your local security requirements) for the alfresco-global.properties file:

```
### Inbound SMTP ###
email.inbound.unknownUser=anonymous
email.inbound.enabled=true
email.server.enabled=true
email.server.port=25
email.server.domain=server.domain.tld
email.server.allowed.senders=.*
```

Sending user...

- e-mail address must be known by Alfresco
- must be a member of EMAIL_CONTRIBUTORS
- must be a member of the destination site
- must have permissions on the destination node

The e-mail address that you send TO is the node ID.  This can be retrieved from 5.0a and earlier by viewing the node in the "Alfresco Explorer" (accessible from the "View Properties" screen in Share (since almost everyone is all Share all the time).  Note that with 5.0b that option may not be available anymore (and I do not know what the replacement is)?

The standard setup for allowing non-registered e-mails to submit documents involves creating the "anonymous" account.  It can be attached to sites and given permissions to nodes just like any other user (since it actually is).  This also means you can get fancy and assign an existing user to be the accepting party for unknown source e-mails.  Note that no matter how you do it, this does open you up to some new risks...